# Ionic/Angular 2 Dependency Injection Not Working According to Pattern

Tags: angular, dependency-injection, ionic2

I'm following the dependency injection pattern from: http://devdocs.io/angular~2_typescript/cookbook/dependency-injection

My code looks like this:

MyService.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class MyService {}
```

app.component.ts

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { MyService } from '../services/MyService';

@Component({
  templateUrl: 'app.html',
  providers: [MyService]
})

export class MyApp {}
```

MyComponent.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'theComponent',
  templateUrl: 'theComponent.html'
})
export class thisComponent {
  constructor(private thisService: MyService) {}
```

I get the following error: *Cannot find name 'MyService'*.

I already checked to make sure that 
"emitDecoratorMetadata": true

I've also tried the public, private and left off the extra discriptor public/private and I get the same error each time.

Comment: Looks like thisComponent is missing the import. (`import { MyService } from '../services/MyService';`) Is this your actualy code?

Comment: @Fiddles, thanks for your response. I'm dying slowly over here on a terrible detail. It's a simplified version of my code. Why do you ask or what do you think is missing? Why do I need to import MyService inside the MyComponent, I thought that was already done via the app.component. Please clarify.

Comment: @ whoever gave me -1, please explain what went wrong. The detail for importing the path to the service was left off the pattern in the documents. Given I'm not the only newbie learning Angular 2 right now, I'm sure there will be others falling into this trap; hopefully I've saved them some time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`import`ing into your class files allows you to use the exported definitions from another file/module. You need to import the class into every file that uses that class definition.

So in `thisComponent.ts`, you'll need to include

> import { MyService } from './path/to/services/MyService';

See https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/doc/spec.md#11.3.2 for more info on what this is doing in Typescript

This is different from the import properties of Modules in Angular2, which are about dependency chains and injectors.

Comment: thanks that worked but what's the point in having a root app.component.ts file and importing it there if I still need to import it everywhere else?

Comment: The short version, is that you need to import the definition to a file to be able to use it in that file.